# enable hot reload for vite react project instead of page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am new to vite and I just started a new react application. My project had hmr (hot module replacement) enabled and it was ok. I just added some changes but when I start it now the hmr is disabled and when adding new change the browser is reloading (not updating fast) and in the terminal it logs:
`12:37:54 PM [vite] page reload src/App.tsx`
I created a new test application and it has hmr enabled and when I add any change it logs:
`12:35:23 PM [vite] hmr update /src/App.tsx (x2)`
Can any you tell me how to enable hmr instead of page reload?

Here is my `vite.config.ts` for project that logs `page reload`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

and also `tsconfig.json`  for project that logs `page reload`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After following the searching; I found this [link](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4577#discussioncomment-1161007). The problem is if any of exports are named exports like `export const foo = 12` this will break hmr. so after changing to `export default function FooBar(){}` hmr is working.

Comment: Mahdi-Jafaree,  I don't know how to express my thanks to you, I was struggling to get the Vite HMR working for the past few days, I am trying to migrate CRA to Vite, and I do have the export statements in my index.tsx and moving them to a separate file worked like a charm,  Thank you so much for this answer.

Answer (score 28):

The solution for me was making sure the case of the component file name matched the import so:

```
import Login from "../components/Login.vue";
```

when the file name was `LogIn.vue` resulted in the login component not reloading on changes (without an error). Changing the import to:

```
import Login from "../components/LogIn.vue"
```

fixed the problem!

Comment: I feel so stupid rn this of the solutions is what worked

Comment: For future google arrivals: tsconfig.json has a field `forceConsistentCasingInFileNames` you want to set to `true`

Answer (score 12):

To enable the hot reload, you need to put this configuration in your vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case I'm using typescript and the solution was to set the `vite.config.js` react plugin like indicated in this Github comment: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4577#discussioncomment-2320990

which is basically this:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      include: "**/*.tsx",
    }),
  ],
});
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. However, I use JS so I used ```include: "**/*.jsx"```

Answer (score 6):

I have experienced this problem recently, here is a solution on how to fix it. If you are using `.jsx` files, you should modify the `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({
    // Add this line
    include: "**/*.jsx",
  })]
})
```

Or, if you are using typescript (`.tsx`), you can modify the `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({
    // Add this line
    include: "**/*.tsx",
  })]
})
```

Hope this solves your issues.

Comment: Doesn't work for me...

Comment: This worked for @vitejs react, if you are using something different, probably there is another problem. You can try in your vite.config.js to enable HMR, with adding the lines - server: { hmr: true }. This enables HMR. As well, try to clear the npm or yarn cache, sometimes that is the issue as well.

Comment: I found the solution just a few minutes after writing this comment. I somehow named the `pages` folder `Pages` and this was the issue in my case. Strange enough instead of showing an error vite continues to run the server with hotreload not working

Comment: Glad you managed to solve it, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue also and after reading the docs more carefully I realized that I only needed to add this to *any* of the js/ts files which vite is aware of (referenced in the index.html file) and it started working:

```js
import.meta.hot
```

Comment: where did you add it to?

Comment: I updated the answer to be more clear

Comment: `where did you add it to` Still not clear? @jaksco

Comment: add the line to any of the `.js` or `.ts` files which vite is aware of. for example if you have an `index.html` file you can create a regular `.js` file and reference the file in a normal `script` tag

Answer (score 1):

Check your tsx filename's first letter is uppecase!

`component.tsx` -> `Component.tsx`

Answer (score 1):

I'm working in my first vite react project and coming from cra it was my habit to use functional "arrow" components.

```
const funcName = () => {...}
```

As soon as I saw the App.jsx had normal function, I changed it to an arrow function.

from this `function App() {...}` to this `const App = () => {...}`

Right from the beginning of the project none of my updates were updated in the browser. I'd to cancel and start the server again to see the updates.

After changing it back to normal function my hmr started working fine.

So as of now, April 2023, the App component must be written in the following manner:

```
function App() {...}
```

Comment: do you have a source for this? was it announced somewhere or in the docs?

Comment: can't think of any source at this point... but this worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me. i edit my vite.config.ts since i am using typescript.

```
plugins: [react({
    include: "**/*.tsx",
  })],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    }
  }
```

Comment: running under bun, this helped me. (restart the server after you change the file)

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was removing the subdirectory for each file inside the pages directory. [Reference](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4577#discussioncomment-2536963)

### My previous folder structure:

```bash
├── src
│   ├── Components
│   ├── Pages
│   │   ├── Home
│   │   │   ├── Home.styled.jsx
│   │   │   ├── Index.jsx
│   │   ├── About
│   │   │   ├── About.styled.jsx
│   │   │   ├── Index.jsx
```

### Fix

It worked when I changed my folder structure to this, and updated my App.jsx to the files directly:

So from this `(./pages/Home/)` to `(./pages/Home.jsx)`

```bash
├── src
│   ├── Components
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── Home.jsx
│   │   ├── About.jsx
```

Comment: for what it's worth your old folder structure was incorrect, it might be that you didn't know because you're on a case insensitive filesystem. the index files should be `index.jsx` not `Index.js`... (additionally it's bad practice to use `index.jsx` implying you've defined react components in your index file, just name them `index.js` and only put exports in there.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks @airtonix

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the import name of the component Is the same as the name of the file where this component lives:

This works:

```
import NewReleases from '../components/homepageComps/NewReleases'
```

This does not:

```
import NewReleases from '../components/homepageComps/OtherNameHere'
```

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing this problem I just run `npm install` after that issue fixed